# R: How to get the CDF plot from PDF data?

Tags: r, cdf

I have a data set that essentially for each observation `x` I have its corresponding "contribution" `y`. This contribution stat is normalized such that the total contribution of all `x` in my dataset sums up to 1. I would like to plot this similar to a CDF plot, so that for each `x` I would plot the cumulative contribution sum at that point.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I imagine I could iterate over my data and recompute a cumulative `y` for each `x`, but I wonder if there are better ways to do this.

Comment: how about `?cumsum`

Comment: Empirical cumulative distribution function: `?ecdf`